# Installing find command in a docker container running RHEL 8

Tags: docker, redhat, yum, rhel8

I am running a docker container of image:

```
confluentinc/confluent-local:7.4.1
```

It is based on Redhat 8.8

How do I install find command in the container?

I tried running:

```
$ yum update
```

and got this error:

```
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS                                                                                                                                                                                       
0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'ubi-8-baseos-rpms':
- Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates 
for https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/aarch64/baseos/os/repodata/repomd.xml [SSL certificate problem: 
unable to get local issuer certificate]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'ubi-8-baseos-rpms': Cannot download 
repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

Is there a way to get the correct rpm/package for find, download it using curl and install it using yum? We do not have RHEL subscription.

Answer (score 1):

1. you cannot install anything using under privilege user

```
alexus@mba ~ % docker run -it confluentinc/confluent-local:7.4.1 id
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
alexus@mba ~ %
```

2. rhel8 ships w/ `dnf` (no longer `yum`)
3. you can't pull packages w/out subscription, period.

Comment: Any workarounds? Can I download packages from CentOS repo using curl/wget and install them manually?

Comment: not sure which "workarounds" you' referring too, but:

1. you can re-build image and include whichever package you'd like to install
2. you can't steal subscription based packages from redhat, at very least it's not ethical and illegal

Comment: I don't have easy access to the Dockerfile. So, unable to build image. I was hoping to get access to a free CentOS repo which has the packages needed to run the find command. So, I could download them using curl.